# Sum of a column in python for CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file and I want to find the total distance that the athlete runs. CSV file is given below how can I add the numbers in column 3.

[image: Sum of C column]

Comment: You are not providing enough information. Where are you stuck? Is reading the file in a problem? Is summing the values the problem? Is the problem that you did not try anything?

Comment: I open the file so I can read it but I don't know how to select the spesific column and add the values

Comment: show us what you are doing

Comment: intervals = (open("RunningIntervals.csv", "r"))

#I dont know what to write here bro that's why I asked how to do it :/

intervals.close()

Comment: use `pandas` module and you do it in 2-3 lines of code

Comment: @furas `pandas` is a pretty heavy dependency if you're not already using it.  This is trivial in plain python as well, see `csv.reader` example in the CSV docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: @therefromhere I know `csv` module but I prefer `pandas` even for so trivial problem because I can do it in 2-3 lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach using the builtin csv module

```
import csv
csv_file = csv.reader(open("your_file_name.csv"))

dist = 0
for row in csv_file:
    _dist = row[2]
    try: 
        _dist = float(_dist)
    except ValueError:
        _dist = 0

    dist += _dist
```

Comment: Yeah that worked for me thanks but what if I also want to find the total time ? I tried the same thing but time becomes 0. But when I delete the code for distance it finds total time properly. What can I do to find both of them ?

Answer (score 4):

Using `pandas` module it might look like (more or less)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filename, ... some other options ...)

print df[2].sum()

# print df['distance'].sum()
```

Comment: No module named pandas

Comment: It is not standard library. You have to install - `pip install pandas`